# how to revert transform box

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I have a photo in photoshop I rotated it and I want the transform border to be straight and not rotated ( straight after rotation ) how can I do that?
Thank everyone
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you rotated, applied the transformation and now you want to reset the angle (rotation) back to 0?

Comment: yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Smart Objects remember the transformation values. So if you convert the layer into a smart object, rotate it and come back later, you can activate free transform and set the angle back to 0.

Comment: that is not I meant, if I rotated an item 30 degree for example and I want it to be my 0 angle, how can I do that?

Comment: That doesn't clarify it at all... Why doesn't converting it into a smart object beforehand work?

Comment: I need the transform control (border) in not rotated in order to the new angle ( I want to make the angle my 0 angel)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand...

Comment: on the left is the old angle with the transform box, the right one is my new angle, I want the transform box to be 0 in order to the new angle

Comment: I don't understand  what you want either, or why @Joonas suggestion to use a Smart Object isn't working for you. Please consider [editing your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/132912/edit) to clarify what you actually want. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can't, unless you know the rotation angle or use Smart Objects as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. This can not be done with standard layers - pixel or vector.

Once a pixel or vector object has been transformed (rotated) and that transformation has been committed, the bounding area has been reset. There is no feature or method to make the bounding box remain or reset to the original object prior the transformation.

Smart objects **do** remember rotation amounts. So you the bounding box remains tied to the overall shape in *smart objects* and will be seen as rotated if you later want to transform again.